# PyCharm code style check via command line

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it possible to run the PyCharm linter / code style checks from command line and get the warnings/errors?

Extension to that: Is it possible to integrate that in my Travis tests?

Comment: Does this help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-code-inspector.html?

Comment: @JulianCamilleri: To some degree. But the doc is very sparse there. E.g. how can I easily install PyCharm (e.g. in Travis, via wget)? And then when I run the inspect, how can I print the output on console (similar as pylint output)? How can I specify what files I want to inspect? ...

Comment: May I ask why you want to use the built in code inspection and not `Black` with `Flake8` for example?

Comment: @JulianCamilleri: Because we use PyCharm anyway for development, and it's great and does a very good job for code checking. I would want that PyLint/Black or whatever gives me almost exactly the same warnings. But this seems non-trivial to achieve, if at all ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323902/)). Also I doubt that it is as powerful.

Comment: I believe you're seeing this from the wrong side. - You shouldn't integrate pycharm into your pipelines, you should integrate your tools into pycharm.

I would personally prefer to work with Black+Flake8 and integrate Black into pycharm. As shown here: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor_integration.html

Comment: @JulianCamilleri Well, maybe, but ultimately I would want to have the best inspection, and I'm quite sure that PyCharm is most powerful there. Even if you would not agree to that, I'm sure that PyCharm support certain checks which are not supported by Black. So maybe I would use both then. In either case, it would be interesting to use also PyCharm. Also, why exactly do you argue that you should not use PyCharm there? You can easily build a standalone command line tool just based on the PyCharm lint code. This is basically what I ask here.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't; I'm just giving you my perspective; I do use the pycharm code inspection too. - but possibly check if black supports the code checks done in pycharm or not.

Comment: @JulianCamilleri: But there are thousands of checks. It would take months to check them all. And in the end, I'm pretty sure I find lots of cases which PyCharm correctly inspects and Black does not. Even if not (very unlikely), then I still have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323902/). And if I find such cases where I cannot use Black, I really would like to automatically check for them, i.e. use the PyCharm linter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put some of the comments and some further research into an answer:

PyCharm comes with a small command-line utility `bin/inspect.sh`, which is documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-code-inspector.html). This tool is quite limited though, and has some problems, e.g. [it cannot run while the PyCharm IDE is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339010/run-pycharm-inspect-sh-even-if-pycharm-is-already-running), and [it reports somewhat incorrectly / different than the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366893/pycharm-bin-inspect-sh-reports-other-warning-invalid-than-ide). Related code can be seen e.g. [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/c00f4154cf89222eadad120bc62947b29f265ee2/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInspection/InspectionApplication.java).
PyCharm does not do PEP8 code style checks by itself but uses the (bundled) pycodestyle tool.

Maybe these shortcomings can be fixed upstream. See e.g. [this report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34863), or [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34864), or [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34865).

I'm using this in Travis and GitHub Actions now, via [this script](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/master/tests/pycharm-inspect.py).
This also does the necessary setup of a project.
This also compensates for the `inspect.sh` missing warnings by also using the pycodestyle tool and thus exactly matching the PyCharm IDE warnings.

Alternative, I'm thinking about writing an extended simple utility which basically does this. All the [relevant PyCharm code is open source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community). I created a project page [pychar-inspect](https://github.com/albertz/pycharm-inspect) for this. But this is just in the planing phase currently, and maybe obsolete when this will be addressed upstream.