# run PyCharm inspect.sh even if PyCharm is already running

Tags: pycharm

When I run `...pycharm/bin/inspect.sh` and PyCharm is already running (the full GUI), I get an error:

```
Already running
```

Is there any way to work around this?

(Or rather: What is the simplest / most elegant way to work around this? I'm quite sure that I can make it work via some LD preload hacks, or maybe some sandbox, or so.)

(I also asked/reported that upstream [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34865).)

Comment: The possible workaround is to install PyCharm to two different locations

Comment: @user2235698: This is what I am already doing, but I still get the same error.